# Recursion with random numbers

Tags: algorithm, recursion, probability

```
function foo(n)  
     if n = 1 then  
        return 1  
     else  
        return foo(rand(1, n))  
     end if  
   end function
```

If foo is initially called with m as the parameter, what is the expected number times that rand() would be called ?

BTW, rand(1,n) returns a uniformly distributed random integer in the range 1 to n.

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: What's `m` variable that you mention?

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/633459/recursion-with-random-number Please use the search function or Google to see whether your question has already been answered before asking a question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple example is how many calls it takes to calculate `f(2)`. Say this time is `x`, then `x = 1 + 0/2 + x/2` because we do the actual call `1`, then with probability `1/2` we go to `f(1)` and with probability `1/2` we stay at `f(2)`. Solving the equation gives us `x = 2`.

As with most running time analysis of recursion, we try to get a recursive formula for the running time. We can use linearity of expectation to proceed through the random call:

```
E[T(1)] = 0
E[T(2)] = 1 + (E[T(1)] + E[T(2)])/2 = 2
E[T(n)] = 1 + (E[T(1)] + E[T(2)] + ... E[T(n)])/n
        = 1 + (E[T(1)] + E[T(2)] + ... E[T(n-1)])/n + E[T(n)]/n
        = 1 + (E[T(n-1)] - 1)(n-1)/n + E[T(n)]/n
```

Hence

```
E[T(n)](n-1) = n + (E[T(n-1)] - 1)(n-1)
```

And so, for `n` > 1:

```
E[T(n)] = 1/(n-1) + E[T(n-1)]
        = 1/(n-1) + 1/(n-2) + ... + 1/2 + 2
        = Harmonic(n-1) + 1
        = O(log n)
```

This is also what we intuitively might have expected, since `n` should approximately half at each call to `f`.

We may also consider the 'Worst case with high probability'. For this it's easy to use Markov's inequality, which says `P[X <= a*E[X]] >= 1-1/a`. Setting `a = 100` we get that with 99% probability, the algorithm makes less than `100 * log n` calls to `rand`.

Comment: Isn't the expected value at n=1 0, since rand isn't called at all? Does that matter in this case?

Comment: Well, you have to do one call, in which the `if n = 1 then` branch is taken.

Comment: @ThomasAhle the question asks for the expected number of rand() calls. I think your analysis is correct (I upvoted), except the details are slightly wrong -- E(T(1)) = 0.

Comment: How about the worst case? How many call would be made to the random function?

Comment: That depends on what you mean by worst case. Normally for random processes like this, we may be interested in the "worst case with 99% probability", or some such number. That shouldn't be more than a constant factor from logn. If you mean worst case as in the random generator always returns n, then obviously you'll end up calling it infinitely many times.